# Making A Search Tag Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

So if you guys are familiar with the YouTube video uploading page, there is a place for adding search tags (similar to adding tags here in stackoverflow) for the video as shown below ->
[image]

The way it works is that after typing in the tag, you put in a " , " and the tag gets added as follows with the little cross on the right to cancel it.

I want to make a similar system using HTML, JS, CSS (Bootstrap).
One way would be to create little bootstrap alerts using JS, but it seems messy.

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of Jquery plugins out there you can use. Since you wanna use Javascript, this is easy.

Some libraries:

- http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/
- https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Both of these will require jQuery.

Edit: Something else you might wanna do:
use https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. With some JS you could use this too, and have a cleaner UI.

Comment: Thanks ! The Bootstrap Tags Input plugin worked great for my purpose !